# Can you override routes and make it database driven?

Tags: scala, playframework

Is it possible to override the default routes file by making it database driven in the playframework?

I want to be able to have routes defined in a more dynamic way instead of hard-coding the routes in a configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, just create a dynamic route as described in [Dynamic parts spanning several /](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting#Dynamic-parts-spanning-several-/) - then in your action divide parts by slash, validate how required and then make your query.

Depending on your DB response you can just call a method which returns a valid `Result`. That's all

Comment: To keep things organized, could I then call other actions based on the dynamic route?  I don't want all my logic to be in a single action.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes you can, as I wrote: _just call a method which returns a valid `Result`_

Comment: Thanks, btw, does chaining method calls like that add any additional overhead?  Meaning, it is creating many layers of futures....

Comment: Don't think so... you can just prepare `Result`   to return in current action, or prepare it in _external_ method, you'll loose maybe 100ms per 10.000 requests, so it doesn't really matters... (must say: just shooting) I didn't observe any massive overheat by using this approach. For sure you'll see performance drop on DB resolving as usually, DB access is always a _bottle neck_

Comment: I see ok, yes the db access will slow it down but I'm not referring to that.  I'm just talking about chaining action methods (this tactic in isolation of what the chained action actually does since I will have to do that logic somewhere).